# Passing angular service to class and base-class

Tags: angular

I have the following class:

```
export class CellLayer extends BaseLayer {

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, private mapService: MapService) {
        super(name, type, mapService);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding abstract class:

```
export abstract class BaseLayer implements ILayer {

    private _name: string;
    private _type: LayerType;

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, private mapService: MapService) {
        this._name = name;
        this._type = type;
    }
}
```

The global `MapService` object should be passed to both classes.

However, I now receive the following error:

> Types have separate declarations of a private property 'mapService'.
>   (6,14): Class 'CellLayer' incorrectly extends base class 'BaseLayer'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make it protected.

`Private` means the property is private to the current class, thus the child component cannot override it nor can it define it.

```
export abstract class BaseLayer implements ILayer {

    private _name: string;
    private _type: LayerType;

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, protected mapService: MapService) {
        this._name = name;
        this._type = type;
    }
}
export class CellLayer extends BaseLayer {

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, protected mapService: MapService) {
        super(name, type, mapService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove `private` from your `CellLayer` constructor and make it `protected` in the `BaseLayer` class. This way you could access the `mapService` member of `BaseLayer` in the `CellLayer` class.

```
export abstract class BaseLayer implements ILayer {

    private _name: string;
    private _type: LayerType;

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, protected mapService: MapService) {
            this._name = name;
            this._type = type;
    }
}

export class CellLayer extends BaseLayer {

    constructor(name: string, type: LayerType, mapService: MapService) {
        super(name, type, mapService);
    }
}
```